# going to the next element in for loop through for statement not the general way

Tags: c++, for-loop

can help me in simple code below??

i commented where problem is

TIA

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
 if(x[i] !=1000)
 {
  //do something
}
 else
  {
 //i want it to go to the next i and again check x[i] != 1000,not i++
   }
  if(y != x[i])
   {

  //do something
}

 }
```

Comment: `else { continue; }` btw what is `j++`?

Comment: This is not very clear.  What's `y` for example?

Comment: what do you mean, "not i++"?  `i++` and "go to the next i" mean the exact same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure who `j` is but you may be looking for this:

```
if(x[i] !=1000)
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //i want it to go to the next i and again check x[i] != 1000,not j++
    continue;
}
```

Comment: i corrected my question thanks

Comment: @arash Do you want to check again `x[i] != 1000` **without incrementing `i`** ?

Comment: no i want to increment i but check from x[i] != 1000

Comment: @arash In that case `continue` will do.

Comment: Why not put the 2nd if into the 1st if?